# How to get previous -previous quarters month and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

- If the date is 2020-07-14, output month:3 year:2020
  previous-previous quarter is 1 and 1st quarter last month is 3
- If the date is 2020-03-14, output month:9 year:2019
  previous-previous quarter is 3 and 3rd quarter last month is 9

Did this for Month:

```
declare @month int;
declare @quarter int

set @quarter= DATEPART(Quarter, '2020-10-14')
set @month = (@quarter - 2) *3

select @month
select @quarter
```

Please do help me with the year. I have searched online gone through Datediff and dateadd functions but it is confusing

Comment: Not quite sure I follow here. 2020-07-14 start of previous quarter would be 2020-04-01 but you said you want the month to be 3. 2020-03-14 has the same issue. The start of the previous quarter would be 2019-10-01. Maybe you want to subtract one month from the start of the previous quarter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the last day of the quarter then here is one solution. This should work going forwards and backwards.

```
DECLARE @ReportDate DATETIME = '2020-07-14'
DECLARE @QuarterInterval INT = -2

DECLARE @EndOfQuarter DATETIME =(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0,DATEADD(QUARTER,@QuarterInterval , @ReportDate)) +1, 0)))

SELECT 
    TheDate = @EndOfQuarter,
    TheMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,@EndOfQuarter),
    TheYear = DATEPART(YEAR,@EndOfQuarter)
```

Comment: This is slightly cleaner: SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @ReportDate) - @QuarterInterval, 0)

Comment: It seems that produces the start of the quarter. Based on the example above, the end of quarter was requested --> 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd find it easier to adjust the date to the first day of the final month of the current quarter then take 6 months off it:

```
declare @quart int;
declare @month int;
declare @thedate date;
set @thedate = '2020-07-14';
set @quart = DATEPART(quarter, @thedate);
set @month = ((@quart - 1) * 3) + 2
set @thedate = DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1)
set @thedate = DATEADD(month, @thedate, -6)
```

If it's the last day of the quarter before last quarter you can use the EOMONTH function to turn this date into the last day of the month rather than the first

You could also consider taking your current date, adding (((MONTH(date) - 1) % 3) - 6) months to it then EOMONTHing it. The formula produces either -4, -5 or -6 depending on whether the month is the first second or third in the quarter (7th is the first month of q3, it becomes -4, and 7-4 = 3, March, the last month of q1). EOMONTH will put the date to last in the month at the end of the math

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try:

```
declare @month int;declare @edate date,@year int;
set @edate= dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, Dateadd(Month,-6,'2020-07-14'))+1,-1)
set @month=month(@edate)
set @year=year(@edate)
select @month
select @year
```